# Simplest and possibly most efficient way to check for data in a line in an array

Tags: c#

I'm making a Connect 4 Console game in C#. I have all the application set up and working correctly except the `hasGameBeenWon()` function. The function is called in the Main do...while loop and returns false when the game has not been won.

```
    static bool gameHasEnded(int currentTurn)
    {
        int currentTurnPiece;

        if (currentTurn.Equals(1))
        {
            currentTurnPiece = BLUE;
        }
        else if (currentTurn.Equals(2))
        {
            currentTurnPiece = RED;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

(obviously, this code is incomplete)

...Is how it current looks, the `currentTurn` var is int value of the current player's turn (it can be either 1 or 2). BLUE and RED are constants that are assigned the values of 1 and 2 that are converted into Blue and Red colours on the board when the application prints to the console.

Now I'm stuck on how to check if the game has been won efficiently and as simple as possible. The board is stored in an Array called `board`, I need to check to see if there is a set of 4 same-values going up/down, left/right and also diagonal in all directions. The checking up/down and left/right is not that hard, but the diagonal I thought maybe a little slow in having to check every single time.

Is there anyway I could speed up checking the entire board or possibly skip checking the entire board altogether and possibly searching just the relevant areas?

Comment: if you are going to post code it may help if you post all relevant code that pertains to your question.. it's hard to determine what you are doing based on that one section of code.. show how `board` is defined as well

Comment: 1) Please use named constants/objects instead of integer literals. 2) Don't bother doing the check in the main `do...while` loop. Instead perform the check _once_ after each move is made. 3) I don't think efficiency should be a prime concern with such a simple check/game. Get it working first with readable/maintainable code, then decide if it needs optimization.

Comment: Add the board array. It should be simple from there

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `board` is just some 2-D array of `enum Cell {NONE, BLUE, RED}` values with `width` and `height` and that you want to "connect `N`" (where in your example `N` is `4`).

A simple vector class:

```
class Vec
{
    public int i;
    public int j;
    public Vec(int i, int j) { this.i = i; this.j = j; }
}
```

The types of patterns/templates that describe a win:

```
var winTemplates = new List<List<Vec>>
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => new Vec(x, 0)).ToList(),
    Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => new Vec(0, x)).ToList(),
    Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => new Vec(x, x)).ToList(),
    Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => new Vec(N - x - 1, x)).ToList()
};
```

Is there a `(Cell, List<Vec>)` tuple describing a win at position `p`?

```
Func<Vec, Tuple<Cell, List<Vec>>> getWin = p => winTemplates
    .SelectMany(winTemplate => winTemplate
        .Select(q => new Vec(p.i + q.i, p.j + q.j))
        .GroupBy(v => board[v.i, v.j])
        .Where(g => g.Key != Cell.NONE && g.Count() == N)
        .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.ToList())))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a win anywhere on the board?

```
Func<Tuple<Cell, List<Vec>>> findWin = () => Enumerable.Range(0, height - N)
    .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(0, width - N).Select(j => new Vec(i, j)))
    .Select(p => getWin(p))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is just browser code, so it may have typos. If you need more help understanding it, let me know in a comment.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I've tried this, but it gives me to error of "Cannot implicitly convert Cell.NONE to Cell.BLUE"

Comment: @Simon Fletcher Are `Cell.NONE` and `Cell.BLUE` not of the same type? I thought `Cell` is an enum?